# Move values around the matrix perimeter - Python / NumPy

Tags: python, numpy

it's necessary that lateral values ​​are shifted along the perimeter.

E.g.  one step twist:

```
1 2 3     4 1 2

4 5 6 ==> 7 5 3

7 8 9     8 9 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach for `2D` arrays -

```
def move_perimeter(a, n, direction='clockwise'):
    # a : input array
    # n : number of elements to be moved
    # direction : 'clockwise' or 'counterclockwise'

    # Dictionary to map for number of elements rolling later
    dirn_map = {'clockwise':n,'counterclockwise':-n}

    # Store size
    m,n = a.shape
    r0 = np.arange(m-1)
    r1 = np.arange(n-1)

    # Get Top, Right, Bottom and Left side linear indices. Store those.
    T = r1
    R = n-1+r0*n
    B = a.size-r1-1
    L = n+r0[::-1]*n
    idx = np.r_[T,R,B,L]

    # Make a copy of input array
    out = a.copy()

    # Linearly index into output array with those original indices
    # and extract rolled values from input array.
    out.ravel()[idx] = a.ravel()[np.roll(idx, dirn_map[direction])]
    return out
```

Sample runs -

```
In [233]: a
Out[233]: 
array([[83, 13, 27, 13],
       [90, 78, 57, 68],
       [66, 47, 44, 53],
       [13, 98, 95, 46],
       [29, 87, 80, 92],
       [91, 19, 86, 26],
       [31, 27, 75, 72]])

In [234]: move_perimeter(a, n=1, direction='clockwise')
Out[234]: 
array([[90, 83, 13, 27],
       [66, 78, 57, 13],
       [13, 47, 44, 68],
       [29, 98, 95, 53],
       [91, 87, 80, 46],
       [31, 19, 86, 92],
       [27, 75, 72, 26]])

In [235]: move_perimeter(a, n=2, direction='counterclockwise')
Out[235]: 
array([[27, 13, 68, 53],
       [13, 78, 57, 46],
       [83, 47, 44, 92],
       [90, 98, 95, 26],
       [66, 87, 80, 72],
       [13, 19, 86, 75],
       [29, 91, 31, 27]])
```

Comment: Doesn't work with:
a = np.matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9')

a2 = move_perimeter(a, n=1, direction='clockwise')

Comment: @АлександрКиберман Don't use `np.matrix`, it's not really popular with NumPy. Use array data : `a = np.array(a)` and then proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Through indices.

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])
indexes = (np.array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1]), np.array([0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 0]))
values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7, 4])
values = np.roll(values, 1)
a[indexes] = values
np.roll ...
```

*For the sake of simplicity of explanation, I printed indexes with hands.*